# How can I pass a value from JavaScript to Swift

Tags: javascript, swift

Here is the code I am using to try and get the length of an item in a websites html to a variable in swift so I can run a function depending on the length of the Class

```
self.viewController?.webBrowser?.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('siteName').length") { (value, error) in
    print("LENGTH IS ", value)
    print("ERROR IS ", error)
    let jsValue = value as? Int

    if jsValue == 0{
        self.waitClick()
    }else{
        self.startItemColor()
    }
}
```

No matter what the length is, I will get 0 as the value

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `DOM Element` was not ready yet when you tried to access it. You should `move` your code to `didFinish` method of `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol.

So your `UIViewController` should look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()

      ...
      webBrowser.navigationDelegate = self
      webBrowser.load(request)
      ...
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('siteName').length") { (value, error) in
            print("LENGTH IS ", value)
            print("ERROR IS ", error)
            let jsValue = value as? Int

            if jsValue == 0{
                self.waitClick()
            } else {
                self.startItemColor()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also don't forget to enable `App Transport Security` in your `info.plist` like this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

In case this doesn't work try to debug why. Probably try to call a method in your JavaScript that returns the length of `class="sitename"` element and also that `console.log(length)` so that you can go further in debugging and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so if an element with that class name is not found, then the array will have `length` of zero. It isn't getting the `length` of the element itself.